# hoe to define own error format for vhdl or verilog code in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I am novice to emacs and elisp. I want to make emacs plugin for displaying output just like vim autofix feature. How to define my error format for verilog or vhdl code. and how will it dispaly errors when the run the compiler?